# Is there a way to limit the scope of the Table of Contents (\tableofcontents command)?

Tags: table-of-contents, input

## Question

If I have a document with multiple tables of contents, can I limit the scope of a toc sections are added and reset the toc?

### Situation

I have a document made up of 10 languages. (using `\input{en}, \input{de}, \input{da}` etc.) There are 11 tables of contents:

- Language Directory (composed of each `\input` (probably going to have to just be a custom table containing hooks for each `\input`. I don't know how I will implement this yet.
- Local table of contents for each specific language (10 languages)

### Example Code

#### Example of Main .tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\maketableofcontents % language directory (list of inputs with language names)
\input{en}
\input{de}
\input{da}
\end{document}
```

#### Example of en.tex

```
\maketableofcontents % local toc
\section{apple}
%\somecommand % TOC scope limit
```

#### Example of de.tex

```
\maketableofcontents % local toc
\section{apfel}
%\somecommand % TOC scope limit
```

#### Example of da.tex

```
\maketableofcontents % local toc
\section{æble}
%\somecommand % TOC scope limit
```

Comment: if you place it the in the main file as: {\maketableocontents \input{en}} does this create the desired effect?

Comment: The package `tableof` has dedicated commands for that

Comment: `etoc` provides means for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `etoc`. [Note the limitations of the default filecontents environment](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/README)

```
\begin{filecontents}{en.tex}
\localtableofcontents
\section{apple}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoc}

% Use this version \newlang{<name>}{<file>}
% to use external files
\newcommand\newlangfile[2]{%
  \newlang{#1}%
  \input{#2}%
}
\newcommand\newlang[1]{%
  \newpage\pdfbookmark{#1}{bkm#1}%
  \renewcommand\contentsname{#1 Contents}%
  \etoctoccontentsline{part}{#1}%
}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Language directory}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


%\newlang{english}
%\localtableofcontents
%\section{Apple}
% Or use 
\newlangfile{english}{en.tex}
% if you prefer the second macro

\newlang{german}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Apfel}
\newlang{danish}
\localtableofcontents
\section{able}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand why `\newlang{german}` comes after `\newlangfile{english}{en.tex}`, but before `\localtableofcontents`. English should have a local TOC and so should German.

Comment: The macro `\newlangfile{english}{en.tex}` does the same as `newlang`, but additionally `\input`s a file (provided by the second argument). This allows you to keep a main file similar to your example using `\input`. Furthermore, I've edited the macro definition to change the Title of every local toc to show that every language has its own toc.

Comment: Awesome! Really, really cool stuff right there...Realistically the `\contentsname` will be set differently, but still, the other possibility of creating a language switch within `\newlangfile` is great.

Comment: I see you are creating toc parts that contain the language names. Is there a way to bring those parts together in a language directory? Also, it would be nice to have those parts show up in the PDF bookmarks. I am not sure at the moment whether that is a job for `tocloft` or `etoc`.

Comment: Ok, it was easy to get the language directory. I just had to temporarily do a `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}`. It would be cool to get the parts into the bookmarks. I think this stuff is beyond the scope of the question, however.

Comment: I have edited the answer again to include bookmarks.

Comment: Do you know if `etoc` messes with the list of figures? I got an error on another document that uses the same preamble after adding `\usepackage{etoc}`.

Comment: No, I don't know about any problems with the list of figures. If I insert some figures and `\listoffigures` in the example above, it works as expected. You should make a new MWE that shows the problem and maybe ask a new question.

Comment: Alight, well another thing that I noticed is that the page numbering for my language directory is off. I even tried getting rid of the `\maketitle` commands.

Comment: This is just a guess, but try to put `\thispagestyle{plain}` directly after your `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: That just changes the printed number, but not counter. The counter is reset by the table of contents I think.

Comment: Without further information (i.e., a MWE) I can only guess. Make a MWE and post a new question.

Comment: I noticed you removed the part about keeping hyperref happy. I was able to fix my page numbers issue (caused by the `titlepage` env). I noticed that my title links point to the first ones mentioned (happen to be English). So section 6 in Danish points to section 6 in English (the first language file loaded and therefore the first section 6). Any chance you could weigh in on this?