# How can I create a list as a variable that can be appended and eventually typeset?

Tags: programming

## Question

In languages such as Python, you can define a list like so:

```
example_list = ['apples']
```

I can append this list like so:

```
example_list.append('oranges')
```

I can print this list using

```
print example_list
```

which results in:

```
['apples', 'oranges']
```

How can I do something similar in LaTeX?

---

This question is part of a trail of questions. The goal mine was to use this list inside of a `tikz` node, but I removed that from this question in the interest of keeping it simple. So, for those interested, *here is a quick list for reference*:

**For making a macro that can handle post-parsing-inputted list items, see:**

- [How can I loop thru a list of inputs that come after \maketitle, yet use that list as part of the \maketitle command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231195/how-can-i-loop-thru-a-list-of-inputs-that-come-after-maketitle-yet-use-that-li)

**For that same solution with `tikz` node support, see:**

- [How can I use a list stored in aux and insert its output into a tikz node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232067/how-can-i-use-a-list-stored-in-aux-and-insert-its-output-into-a-tikz-node)

---

### Situation

I have a list of inputted languages ([see my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228980/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-scope-of-the-table-of-contents-tableofcontents-com)). I would like to capture each language code into a list that I can print to paper as an inline list (i.e. da, de, en, etc.)

I would like to title page to look like this:

TITLE

da, de, en ... (or instead of ISO 639-1 codes, a list of full language names)

---

## Appendage

There are a few good answers already. Although the original question was answered, my problem was not solved due to some other things I did not originally think about. :( Maybe somebody can help me.

I have a list of documents to input

## Pseudo-Code

### List based on Werner's answer

```
\maketitle[\printlist{languagelist}]{User Manual}
\inputlanguagefile{En}{English}{./Languages/en/UserManual_en.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{Da}{Dansk}{./Languages/da/UserManual_da.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{De}{Deutsch}{./Languages/de/UserManual_de.tex}
```

I have a custom `\maketitle` command where the mandatory input `{}` is the title of the document and the optional `[]` is the subtitle (list of ISO 639-1 language codes) My problem is that the `\maketitle` command is called before the file inputs are called, which means that at the time the language list is called, it is still empty. I need to find a way to loop the input commands one by one to grab the two-letter language codes (#1) and append them to my list.

Then I want to actually add the inputs after the `\maketitle` as shown in the sudo-code. Obviously, the inputted documents should appear after the cover page, but I need to parse the language codes before the `maketitle` page is called.

Comment: Either you use the `etoolbox` `\dolistloop` etc. macros or the list features of `expl3`

Comment: Both [pythontex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) and [sagetex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) let you work with Python code in your LaTeX document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides a host of list managing tools. Here is one way using `\listadd{<stuff>}` that seems to match your requirements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% \printlist[<sep>]{<list macro>}
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][,]{{% Print list
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
  \def\listsep{\def\listsep{#1}}% Delayed execution of list separator
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\listsep`##1'}%
  [\dolistloop\languagelist]
}}
\begin{document}

\listadd{\languagelist}{de}
\listadd{\languagelist}{da}
\listadd{\languagelist}{en}

\printlist{\languagelist}

\end{document}
```

There are other ways to add list elements (pre-expanded, globally, etc.). The only requirement is that you define the elements contained in `\languagelist` before printing it via `\printlist`. That is, it doesn't work like the `\label`-`\ref` system where you can refer to *future* `\label`s.

Comment: How can I get rid of the brackets? I see that I can remove the quotations here `{\listsep '##1'}` > `{\listsep ##1}`

Comment: @macmadness86: I used `[\dolistloop\languagelist]`, but you're probably interested in `\dolistloop\languagelist` (without the brackets `[`...`]`).

Answer (score 4):

A rather flexible list management can be obtained with `expl3` and `xparse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listset}{O{default}m}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listappend}{O{default}m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listprint}{O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { macmadness/lists } { #1 }
  \macmadness_print_list:V \l__macmadness_list_name_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l_macmadness_list_default_seq
\tl_new:N \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl

\keys_define:nn { macmadness/lists }
 {
  name .tl_set:N       = \l__macmadness_list_name_tl,
  name .initial:n      = default,
  action .code:n       = \cs_set_eq:NN \__macmadness_action:n #1,
  action .initial:n    = \use:n,
  separator .tl_set:N  = \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl,
  separator .initial:n = { ,~ },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \macmadness_print_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_if_empty:cTF { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
   {
    $\langle$ \textit{empty~list} $\rangle$
   }
   {
    % split off the last item
    \seq_pop_right:cN { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl
    % print the items followed by the separator
    \seq_map_inline:cn
     { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
     {
      \__macmadness_action:n { ##1 } % the item
      \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl % the separator
     }
    % print the last item
    \__macmadness_action:n { \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \macmadness_print_list:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\addquotes}[1]{`#1'}

\begin{document}

\listset{apples}
\listappend{oranges,strawberries}

\listprint

\listprint[
  separator={ $|$ },
  action=\addquotes
]

\listset[languages]{de,da,en}

\listprint[
  name=languages,
  action=\addquotes,
]

\listset[empty]{}

\listprint[name=empty]

\end{document}
```

Lists are identified by a name given as optional argument to `\listset` or `\listappend`. Without the optional argument the name is `default`.

The command `\listprint` receives an optional list of key-value pairs. Keys are

- `name` for telling what list to print (`name=default` is implicit);
- `separator` for telling how to separate items, default is “comma and space”;
- `action` should receive as value a one parameter macro; in the example it's `\addquotes`, but it can be `\textit` or any predefined or personal macro; default is just printing the item.

[image]

You can use `action` for any action you like, for example for inputting files. I created `UserManual_de.tex`, `UserManual_en.tex` and `UserManual_de.tex` with some mock text in them (just “This is the German|English|Danish manual”) and defined a suitable `\inputlanguagefile` action.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listset}{O{default}m}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listappend}{O{default}m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listprint}{+O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { macmadness/lists } { #1 }
  \macmadness_print_list:V \l__macmadness_list_name_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l_macmadness_list_default_seq
\tl_new:N \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl

\keys_define:nn { macmadness/lists }
 {
  name .tl_set:N       = \l__macmadness_list_name_tl,
  name .initial:n      = default,
  action .code:n       = \cs_set_eq:NN \__macmadness_action:n #1,
  action .initial:n    = \use:n,
  separator .tl_set:N  = \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl,
  separator .initial:n = { ,~ },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \macmadness_print_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_if_empty:cTF { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
   {
    $\langle$ \textit{empty~list} $\rangle$
   }
   {
    % split off the last item
    \seq_pop_right:cN { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl
    % print the items followed by the separator
    \seq_map_inline:cn
     { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
     {
      \__macmadness_action:n { ##1 } % the item
      \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl % the separator
     }
    % print the last item
    \__macmadness_action:n { \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \macmadness_print_list:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\addquotes}[1]{`#1'}
\newcommand{\inputlanguagefile}[1]{%
  \input{UserManual_#1}%
}

\listset[languages]{de,da,en}


\begin{document}

\title{\listprint[name=languages]}
\author{macmadness86}

\maketitle

\section{Examples of list management}

\listset{apples}
\listappend{oranges,strawberries}

\listprint

\listprint[
  separator={ $|$ },
  action=\addquotes
]

\listprint[
  name=languages,
  action=\addquotes,
]

\listset[empty]{}

\listprint[name=empty]

\section{The manuals}

\listprint[
  name=languages,
  separator=\par\bigskip,
  action=\inputlanguagefile,
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good to have another solution. Maybe you can have a look at my appendage above.

Comment: @macmadness86 Easy enough. `;-)`

Comment: Well, not really. As it stands, you manually created the list named languages, right? I want it to be generated (the principle of only typing code once) from the `\inputlanguagefile` commands. This makes the code scalable with minimal chances for errors. I am pretty sure I need a loop for this.

Comment: @macmadness86 I can't understand what you're saying: the list of languages is created in the preamble and you *don't* issue `\inputlanguagefile` explicitly. Please, don't ask XY questions.

Comment: @macmadness86 Your problem is *completely* different from what you stated in the question, that's what I'm trying to say. Please, ask a new question stating the real problem. It should be easy to solve by using the `.aux` file.

Comment: While I agree that a new question is needed of course, I would point out that it is not *completely* different. For example, I *did* reference my other question and illustrate that the list should be a subtitle (I mistakenly did not explicitly mention the word subtitle, so it was impossible for you to know that of course. I should have been more clear).

Comment: I added a new question addressing my specific issue here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231195/how-can-i-loop-thru-a-list-of-inputs-that-come-after-maketitle-yet-use-that-li

Comment: I don't see how the `#1` is transferred to `l_macmadness_list_#1_seq` in `\cs_new_protected:Npn`. Could you explain that?

Comment: @macmadness86 The `c` type means that a control sequence is built from the argument. So `\seq_pop_right:cN { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl` is equivalent to `\seq_pop_right:NN { \l_macmadness_list_XYZ_seq \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl` if the argument to the `\macmadness_print_list:n` macro is `XYZ`

Answer (score 2):

This uses the `etoolbox` package and adds some list elements in a row using `\forcsvlist{\listadd{\myfruitlist}}{element1,element2,element3}` etc.

Single elements can be added with `\listadd{\myfruitlist}{element}` or `\listgadd`, `\listeadd`, `\listxadd`, depending on the needs of expansion/global availability.

The output/processing of lists can be done with (for example) `\forlistloop` and an element processing macro, `\printfruitlist`. There are other routines, see the documentation of `etoolbox` on this.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\myfruitlist{}


\newcommand{\printfruitlist}[1]{%
\textbf{#1} 

}%

\begin{document}
\forcsvlist{\listadd{\myfruitlist}}{apples,oranges,strawberries}

\listadd{\myfruitlist}{salad}
\listadd{\myfruitlist}{bananas}

Find the error in this list:

\forlistloop{\printfruitlist}{\myfruitlist}


\end{document}
```

[image]