# How can I iterate over a newline-delimited text file?

Tags: macros, lists, expl3, latex3

Would I need to use a token list?

For the purpose of removing confusion, let there be two delimiters:

1. input delimiter (what LaTeX reads as input)
2. output delimiter (what is seen on paper)

I would like to loop over and grab items from a file containing a list of files:

```
apples.tex
bananas.tex
strawberries.tex
```

## Example

I have tried using LaTeX3 code based on [How can I create a list as a variable that can be appended and eventually typeset?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231055/how-can-i-create-a-list-as-a-variable-that-can-be-appended-and-eventually-typese/231077#231077), but it is nerve-wrecking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listset}{O{default}m}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } { #2 } % input delimiter? (due to clist? "comma list"?)
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listappend}{O{default}m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }% input delimiter? (due to clist? "comma list"?)
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listprint}{+O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { macmadness/lists } { #1 }
  \macmadness_print_list:V \l__macmadness_list_name_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l_macmadness_list_default_seq
\tl_new:N \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl

\keys_define:nn { macmadness/lists }
 {
  name .tl_set:N       = \l__macmadness_list_name_tl,
  name .initial:n      = default,
  action .code:n       = \cs_set_eq:NN \__macmadness_action:n #1,
  action .initial:n    = \use:n,
  separator .tl_set:N  = \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl, % output delimiter
  separator .initial:n = { ,~ }, % output delimiter
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \macmadness_print_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_if_empty:cTF { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
   {
    $\langle$ \textit{empty~list} $\rangle$
   }
   {
    % split off the last item
    \seq_pop_right:cN { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl    % print the items followed by the delimiter
    \seq_map_inline:cn
    \seq_map_inline:cn
     { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
     {
      \__macmadness_action:n { ##1 } % the item
      \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl % output delimiter
     }
    % print the last item
    \__macmadness_action:n { \l__macmadness_list_lastitem_tl }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \macmadness_print_list:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\listprint[%
    separator={ , } % output delimiter
]%
\end{document}
```

Comment: But the lines of fruit in the first box are not delimited by `\par`. `\par` is a _blank line_.

Comment: I would use `textmerg` for merging in the list of files. But I have no idea how people answering know the content of those files to answer the output bit of the question. l3 is great but it just seems like overkill for the first merge, at least. (Though maybe `textmerg` does extravagant non-l3 things...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your input is in a file, you need to grab the file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-list.tex}
apples.tex
bananas.tex
strawberries.tex
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listset}{O{default}m}
 {
  \macmadness_listset:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\listprint}{+O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { macmadness/lists } { #1 }
  \macmadness_print_list:V \l__macmadness_list_name_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \macmadness_listset:nn
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
  \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_macmadness_file_contents_tl {} {#2}
  \seq_set_split:cnV { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } { ~ } \l_macmadness_file_contents_tl
  \seq_pop_right:cN { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {cnV}

\keys_define:nn { macmadness/lists }
 {
  name .tl_set:N       = \l__macmadness_list_name_tl,
  name .initial:n      = default,
  action .code:n       = \cs_set_eq:NN \__macmadness_action:n #1,
  action .initial:n    = \use:n,
  separator .tl_set:N  = \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl, % output delimiter
  separator .initial:n = { ,~ }, % output delimiter
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \macmadness_print_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_if_empty:cTF { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
   {
    $\langle$ \textit{empty~list} $\rangle$
   }
   {
    \seq_clear:N \l_macmadness_output_seq
    \seq_map_inline:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_macmadness_output_seq { \__macmadness_action:n { ##1 } }
     }
    \seq_use:NV \l_macmadness_output_seq \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \macmadness_print_list:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nn { NV }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\listset{\jobname-list}

\listprint

\listprint[separator={; }]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried `\listset{\input{Documents.txt}}`, but it did not work. What am I doing wrong here? Documents.txt exists in the same folder as the tex file.

Comment: @macmadness86 `\listset{Documents.txt}`. If you make your question more precise, I may add different ways for setting the list: from a file or from direct input.

Comment: I've seen you lately *not declaring* certain variables, in this case `\l__macmadness_list_name_tl`, you just use `.tl_set:N` and `.initial:n` it. Why not declaring it with `\tl_new:N` before? Isn't that *the good way*?

Comment: @Manuel The variables used for `.tl_set:N` or any other `.<type>_set:N` declaration are automatically initialized. From `interface3.pdf`, about `.tl_set:N`: “If the variable does not exist, it will be created globally at the point that the key is set up.”

Comment: @Manuel For stuff working with `l3keys` we (I) made a decision that the keys themselves were declarative enough to allow 'short-cutting' the need to apply `\<var>_new:N` when coupled with `.<var>_set:N`. I hope this is a reasonable balance.

Comment: @egreg Why do you need the `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \macmadness_print_list:n { V }
`? I get the `\NewDocumentCommand{\listprint}` calling the `\macmadness_print_list:V \l__macmadness_list_name_tl` and subsequentially calling `\cs_new_protected:Npn \macmadness_print_list:n #1`. When is this variant triggered and how?

Comment: @macmadness86 The macro `\listprint` uses data gathered in `\l__macmadness_list_name_tl`, so I need the `V` variant, but one has to define `\macmadness_print_list:n` first.

Comment: @egreg Ok, another question. Why does using `\item` as a separator not work even when I surround `listprint` by an appropriate list environment like `enumerate`?

Comment: @macmadness86 `\begin{enumerate}\item\listprint[separator=\item]\end{enumerate}` works for me. The *separator* is inserted only *between* items. If you need a *prefix*, it can be worked out.